# jQuery, issue with bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to build a dynamic dropdown menu following http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/jquery-dropdown/

So my code is:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
<body>
<p>
        <a href="#" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">Here’s a link</a>
        and here’s a button <input type="button" value="Dropdown" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1" class="">
        and here’s a <span class="example" data-dropdown="#dropdown-1">span</span>
    </p>
<div id="dropdown-1" class="dropdown dropdown-tip" style="display: block; left: 204.671875px; top: 1373.265625px;">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#1">Item 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#2">Item 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#3">Item 3</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#4">Item 4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Item 5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#5">Item 6</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But nothing happens and I really don't understand why.

Comment: You want to make a bootstrap dropdown menu or you want to build it with the jquery-dropdown plugin?

Comment: You haven't closed your `<input>` tag, although there are most likely further problems after you fix that.

Comment: your code should probably work after loading the plugin css and js, refer to @Ali Sheikhpour answer
and this is an example https://jsfiddle.net/rf5t7xj6/
btw, i think your <div id="dropdown-1" ..> should not have these style="display: block; left: 204.671875px; top: 1373.265625px;"
I guess it was because you copy the example in console directly.

Answer (score 1):

Download project files and include them in your project. the order of included files is important:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.dropdown.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.dropdown.js"></script>
```